# How to return the value without using the switch and if else in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I am new to the react . here I have an  object which has some pre defined values. like

```js
{
    evalues: {
        status: {
            "statusVal": {
                "pre": "PRE",
                "buy": "BYE",
                "close": "CLOSE",
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to return a different icon given a status:

```js
const getIcons = (givenStatus) =>
{
    let close = config?.appConfig?.evalues?.status?.statusVal.close
    let buy = config?.appConfig?.evalues?.status?.statusVal.buy
    let pre = config?.appConfig?.evalues?.status?.statusVal.pre

    if (givenStatus === close)
        return 'yellow'
    else if (givenStatus === buy)
        return 'green'
    else if (givenStatus === pre)
        return 'red'
}
```

Is there another way to do this using `lodash`?

Answer (score 0):

We can use object destructuring to get `buy`, `close`, and `pre` all in one statement. With your current code, this is probably as clean as you can get:

```js
const getIcons = status =>
{
    const { buy, close, pre } = config.appConfig.evalues.status.statusVal

    if (status === buy)
        return 'green'
    if (status === close)
        return 'yellow'
    if (status === pre)
        return 'red'
}
```

Though if the values are guaranteed you can use a `switch` statement instead:

```js
const getIcons = status =>
{
    switch (status)
    {
        case 'BYE':   return 'green'
        case 'CLOSE': return 'yellow'
        case 'PRE':   return 'red'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use ternary operator if you don't want to use switch and if/else, like so:

```
return givenStatus === "close" ? "yello" : givenStatus === "buy" ? "grenn" : givenStatus === "pre" ? "red" : null;
```

You could make this shorter if you're sure that givenStatus can only be either of the three and never nullish/empty;

```
return givenStatus === "close" ? "yello" : givenStatus === "buy" ? "grenn" : "red";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this if you want to avoid `switch` and `if..else`

```js
var statusVal =  {
        "pre": "PRE",
        "buy": "BYE",
      }
      
 var pre = 
(Object.values(statusVal).filter(i=>i === "PRE")).length ? 'yellow' : null;

var buy = (Object.values(statusVal).filter(i=>i === "BYE")).length ? 'grenn' : null;

var close = (Object.values(statusVal).filter(i=>i === "CLOSE")).length ? 'red' : null;
 
 
 console.log(pre);
  console.log(buy);
   console.log(close);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code,To How to return the value without using the switch and if else in javascript

```
function phoneticLookup(val) {
  var result = "";

  switch(val) {
    case "alpha": 
      result = "Adams";
      break;
    case "bravo": 
      result = "Boston";
      break;
    case "charlie": 
      result = "Chicago";
      break;
    case "delta": 
      result = "Denver";
      break;
    case "echo": 
      result = "Easy";
      break;
    case "foxtrot": 
      result = "Frank";
      break;
    default:
    result = '';
    break;

  }

  return result;
}

phoneticLookup("undefined");
```

I hope this code will be useful.

Thank you.

Comment: You could very easily simplify this code by throwing all of the values into an object, like  `const lookup = { 'alpha': 'Adams', ... }`, then returning `lookup[val] || ''`. Makes this basically a one-liner.